# loadHTML returning empty, html is fine

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I'm trying to grab the href value of an element using PHP, but I'm having some trouble. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
  <?php
  ini_set("log_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
  $target_url = "http://foo.bar";
  $request = $target_url;
  $html = $this->scraper($request);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML($html);
  // Error point - $dom is empty
  error_log("dom:");
  error_log($dom);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  error_log("setting target url");
  $target_url = $xpath->query("//*[@class='foo_bar']/href");
  ?>
```

Logging $html results in the standard, full HTML output of the page. A search shows that my xpath should work. However, when I try to log $dom after loadHTML, I get a blank result. I've been struggling for a few hours trying to work out why, but with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas/anything I could try?

Edited to add console output:

```
    [30-Sep-2015 13:51:59 America/New_York] dom:
    [30-Sep-2015 13:51:59 America/New_York] setting target url
```

Comment: `$this->scraper($request);` if your php code REALLY starts at this <?php part, you're calling a member function of an object that does not exists. I didn't see `scraper` function being defined anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't, the scraper function is elsewhere. This code is part of another function. The scraper part works fine, and is used in other functions on other sites without issue.

Comment: And what does it return?

Comment: Edited to add the output :)

Comment: I'm sorry, let me rephrase: what does `scraper($request)` return?

Comment: Apologies. It grabs the html of the page using CURL, with some additional options (custom useragent, no header, set timeout, use proxy, etc) and returns it. I could give the result of google.com if it'd help, but it's literally just a bunch of curl_setopts, $ret = curl_exec, curl_close, return $ret. HTML seems to be as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the HTML was loaded into the DOM. You can use a debugger, the logging or var_dump() for that.

`var_dump($dom->saveXml());`

If its wasn't loaded into DOM take a step back and validate that the HTML was fetched by the scraper.

`var_dump($html);`

If the HTML was loaded into the DOM you will still need to fix the Xpath. I would expect `href` being an attribute node.

`//*[@class='foo_bar']/@href`

You seem to want to read it as a string value, so cast it:

`string(//*[@class='foo_bar']/@href)`

That only works with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, `DOMXpath::query()` can only return node lists.

```
$target_url = $xpath->evaluate("string(//*[@class='foo_bar']/@href)");
```

A small example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml('<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//a[1]/@href)'));
```

Output:

```
string(18) "http://example.com"
```